# formatting data detectors in mail on iosx

Tags: ios, email, formatting

I have seen lots of posts about turning off data detectors in safari & in html emails when viewed in ios but...

I'd like to know if anyone knows how to actually format the auto generated links?

In my email signatire i'd like to be able to style the data detector links as well as hyperlinks but this doesn't seem possible.

Any advice welcome,

Thanks,
Steve.